# WebDriver find a particular child element

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a HTML like this:

```html
<div class="classDiv">
  <header>
    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn-icon-only pull-right ng-scope" type="button">
   <span class="btn-box">
     <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
  <span class="icon-btn icon-edit2" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </span>
    </button>
    <h3 class="classH3">Text1</h3>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="classDiv">
  <header>
    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn-icon-only pull-right ng-scope" type="button">
   <span class="btn-box">
     <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
  <span class="icon-btn icon-edit2" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </span>
    </button>
    <h3 class="classH3">Text2</h3>
  </header>
</div>
```

The problem is every tag is the same, only the text of H3 is different for each div. I want to click only one particular Edit button, for example the second Edit button.

So I tried to find second H3 and from there I tried to find the second Edit button, like this:

```
WebElement hText = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'Text2')]"));
WebElement editBtn = hText.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Edit')]"));
editBtn.click();
```

But it always clicks on the first Edit button. I want to find the parent element, and from parent to find its child. But in this case, every tag is the same, so I don't know how to look for a particular child. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
WebElement divWithH3 = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("div[.//h3[contains(., 'Text2')]]"));
WebElement editBtn = divWithH3.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.//span[contains(text(), 'Edit')]]"));
editBtn.click();
```

This first finds the `div` element that contains your "Text2" element. From there you are searching for a `button` element, that has a `span` element that contains the text "Edit"

Comment: Thanks so much, it works like a charm, that's what I meant

Comment: good to hear! all the best for your project!

Answer (score 0):

If I don't remember bad (//button)[1] or (//button)[2] let you select the button based on his position on the returned list of button